# How Can I Add '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom' To Alfred Search Scope?

Tags: macos-ventura, alfred

I am quite new to MacOS. Alfred does not detect applications installed with `brew install --cask` command. The only answers that I encounter are 'add Caskroom to Alfred search scope` without telling me how.

[image: An Image of Alfred Preferences]

Clicking '+' button opens Finder, but it does not let me select '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom'. (How can I use absolute path in Finder?) I have looked for CLI ways to add path to Alfred search scope, and the searching was unsuccessful. I also have disabled Spotlight index. Absolute path to discord.app is `/Application/Discord.app`. Although `/Application` is already added to Alfred's search scope, Alfred cannot detect Discord, alongside with other apps in `/Application` directory. Please help me have Alfred detect Discord (and other apps such as Brave browser) installed with `brew install --cask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, `sudo mdutil -a -i on` made Alfed detect Discord and other apps.
This command is to enable indexing for spotlight and apparently for Alfred as well.